# find next postion knowing lat/lon/heading/speed

Tags: c#, algorithm, gps

knowing
a **decimal latitude**, **decimal longitude**, **speed (km/h)**, **heading**
how to find the **next position** of a car after 60 seconds?
is there any algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might help:

```
distance_traveled = speed * time
```

Then, calculate x and y components of speed using heading as angle (trigonometry):

```
speed_x=distance_traveled * Math.Cos(heading/180*Math.PI)
speed_y=distance_traveled * Math.Sin(heading/180*Math.PI)
```

Next, see how to map lat/long into some form of x/y coordinates, add speed_x and speed_y, and convert to lat/long again.

This last one is a tricky one, look here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

In fact, you'll find everything within that article!

Comment: I dont see any representation of x,y coordinates on that website ...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I've found more accurate formula

 This code work for me :

 1. First we have to count the distance ( speed * time ).

 2. In my program, i convert the distance to KM because I use earth radius in KM too.

 const double radiusEarthKilometres = 6371.01f;

```
            kmDistance = kmSpeed * (timer1.Interval / 1000f) / 3600f;

            var distRatio = kmDistance / radiusEarthKilometres;
            var distRatioSine = Math.Sin(distRatio);
            var distRatioCosine = Math.Cos(distRatio);

            var startLatRad = deg2rad(lat0);
            var startLonRad = deg2rad(lon0);

            var startLatCos = Math.Cos(startLatRad);
            var startLatSin = Math.Sin(startLatRad);

            var endLatRads = Math.Asin((startLatSin * distRatioCosine) + (startLatCos * distRatioSine * Math.Cos(angleRadHeading)));

            var endLonRads = startLonRad
                + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(angleRadHeading) * distRatioSine * startLatCos,
                    distRatioCosine - startLatSin * Math.Sin(endLatRads));

            newLat = rad2deg(endLatRads);
            newLong = rad2deg(endLonRads);
```